# Feature request: a reward that is transferable to another stack

Tags: feature-request, privileges, se-sites

Recently there was a post on the music stack by someone who had written a tune on a guitar using a tuning of his own invention. I would have liked to comment that Elizabeth Cotten wrote music on a guitar tuned backwards and that Worrell's "Spanish Fandango" is the reason the tuning he used is called "Spanish tuning." Although I had enough reputation to comment on other stacks, I had zip at the music stack.

I think it might be a good idea to have an award of the ability to comment on one stack of the recipient's choice for which he had little or no reputation. What do others think?

Answer (score 9):

This already exists, somewhat, in the form of an [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648).

Essentially, if you earn 200 reputation on any Stack Exchange site, then each of your associated accounts on Stack Exchange sites will earn 100 reputation immediately. Even if you just create them! This is usually enough to get the basic [privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), such as

- set bounties (usually 75 repuation)
- comment everywhere (usually 50 repuation)
- flag posts (usually 15 repuation)
- vote up (usually 10 reputation)

The one thing this bonus is not good for is answering ["protected" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764).